# php if/elseif not working at all

Tags: php, if-statement

The page that calls this script allows the user to pick from 1 to 5 fields. The idea is to add up the number of fields selected and fetch the appropriate results. No matter how many fields are selected from the form the if/elseif statements do not work and I cannot see the problem.  **Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$fields_select = 0;
if($country_type != "") {
  $fields_select = $fields_select + 1;
  $winearr[] = "\$country_type";
  $winearr[] = "Country";
}
if($region_type != "") {
  $fields_select = $fields_select + 1;
  $winearr[] = "\$region_type";
  $winearr[] = "Region";
}
if($wine_type != "") {
  $fields_select = $fields_select + 1;
  $winearr[] = "\$wine_type";
  $winearr[] = "Type";
}
if($rating_type != "") {
  $fields_select = $fields_select + 1;
  $winearr[] = "\$rating_type";
  $winearr[] = "Rating";
}
if($vintage_type != "") {
  $fields_select = $fields_select + 1;
  $winearr[] = "\$vintage_type";
  $winearr[] = "Vintage";
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  if ($fields_select == 0) {
    echo "No Results Found In Search";
  } elseif ($fields_select == 1) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($winearr[0] == $row[$winearr[1]]) {
        makeListing($row); // call the function
      }
    }
  } elseif ($fields_select == 2) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($winearr[0] == $row[$winearr[1]] && $winearr[2] == $row[$winearr[3]]) {
        makeListing($row); // call the function
      }
    }
  } elseif ($fields_select == 3) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($winearr[0] == $row[$winearr[1]] && $winearr[2] == $row[$winearr[3]] && $winearr[4] == $row[$winearr[5]]) {
        makeListing($row); // call the function
      }
    }
  } elseif ($fields_select == 4) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($winearr[0] == $row[$winearr[1]] && $winearr[2] == $row[$winearr[3]] && $winearr[4] == $row[$winearr[5]] && $winearr[6] == $row[$winearr[7]]) {
        makeListing($row); // call the function
      }
    }
  } elseif ($fields_select == 5) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($winearr[0] == $row[$winearr[1]] && $winearr[2] == $row[$winearr[3]] && $winearr[4] == $row[$winearr[5]] && $winearr[6] == $row[$winearr[7]] && $winearr[8] == $row[$winearr[9]]) {
        makeListing($row); // call the function
      }
    }
  }
}
/* Debug */
echo $winearr[0]."-".$winearr[1]."-".$winearr[2]."-".$winearr[3]."-".$winearr[4]."-".$winearr[5]."-".$winearr[6]."-".$winearr[7]."-".$winearr[8]."-".$winearr[9];
echo "<br>\$fields_select=".$fields_select;
```

Comment: Did you do any debug? What's the value of `$fields_select`?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I gusset you are trying to search something by php which is not correct. Try to search by your query and let your database handle the search.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ";

if($country_type != "") {
    $sql .= 'Country = "' .  $country_type .'"';
}
if($region_type != "") {
    $sql .= 'AND Region = "' .  $region_type .'"';
}
.
.
.
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            makeListing($row); // call the function
    }
}
```

in the end fetch your result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Saeed Am.  The visitor needs to look up a wines by all kinds of different criteria.  I can access with just one simple statement.  This database need a much more complex combination of possible ways to search.

Comment: I didn't understand you saying " I can access with just one simple statement." but if you have access to database for avoiding any complexity you can use `FULL TEXT INDEX` on several columns and then use `MATCH() ... AGAINST ` statement. I'm assuming you use MySQL.

Comment: another thing, I don't know what are you trying to do with this `$winearr[] = "\$country_type";` you can simply do this `$winearr[] = $country_type`

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved** - The problem is incorrect coding. $winearr[] = "\$country_type"; returns $country_type instead of the variable that was selected.  Instead of $country_type being equal to Australia, is was literally $country_type every time no matter want was select.

```
$winearr[] = "\$rating_type";
```

should have been

```
$winearr[] = $rating_type;
```

The routine now works exactly as it should.